# Selecting windows drop down menu items

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, win32gui

I know win32api is able to FindWindow(None, "Title of some window)

But how do I find and select drop down menu items?

Reading the module chm, I can't find any straight foward way of doing this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> But how do I find and select drop down menu items?

You need a Window handle. You can find it with [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx). You can also enumerate Windows with [`EnumWindows function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Look for the one with a `COMBOBOX` windows class. See [About Window Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

You then use the `SetSel()` method on the combo box, which wraps [`EM_SETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).